# Is their any change to move a wallet from an bnb blockchain to an ethereum blockchain?

Tags: transactions, wallets, cpp-ethereum, error

I transferred some ethereum to my bnb wallet. Later I found out that this bnb wallet is not on the ethereum platform.

So I send an amount of ETH to an address similar to the address of the bnb wallet (but that bnb wallet is not the same wallet as the wallet I send the eth to).

Info of the wallet I send my eth to:
https://etherscan.io/address/0x7C7ffb0d9a3cB52265b2224b1358b56916A6e199

info of the bnb wallet:
https://bscscan.com/address/0x7C7ffb0d9a3cB52265b2224b1358b56916A6e199

you see that the address of both wallets are identical.. but they are not the same!

if someone can explain how this, or if someone might know if I will ever see my eth back u will be rewarded! :)

kind regards,
Dennis Franke

Comment: No. Different blockchains do not share anything. It's done and lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same private key on multiple Ethereum compatible blockchains and all of the blockchains have the same address format. MetaMask allows you even to switch between different chains from the menu without the need to recreate the wallet.

Comment: were can i find this private key?

Comment: im not sure what to do now. I dont know if u understand me correctly. But i dont have acces to the wallet on the eth network.

Comment: Depends on the wallet. I suggest you write email tot he support email of the wallet vendor.